# Yii2 Call to a member function saveAs() on a non-object

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

So I followed a Yii2 tutorial on youtube by doingiteasychannel however I get the following error when clicking the submit button.

```
Call to a member function saveAs() on a non-object
```

Below is some of the code within the controller action I habe created the form and added the enctype but still gives an error.

The below code should save the file to a directory and then add the path to the file into the avatar column of my table.

```
$userprofile = UserProfile::findOne(['user_id' => $id]);     

$imageName = $user->username;
$userprofile->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($userprofile, 'file');
$userprofile->file->saveAs('uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$userprofile->file->extension);
$userprofile->avatar = 'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$userprofile->file->extension;
$userprofile->user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
$userprofile->save(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please declare a property (variable) `file` in your `UserProfile` model and assign its validation rule in `rules()` method - [reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html)

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user". (for eg)
 *
 * ...
 */
class UserProfile extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    // for file uploading
    public $file;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // ... other attribute validation rules
            [['file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
        ];
    }

    /**    
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user'; // for eg
    }

    // ... rest of the code
```

Comment: cheers i found the solution but it's exactly as youve got above.